# xamarin forms: how to detect if leaving the page is back to previous page or new page?

Tags: forms, xamarin

One of the page in my xamarin forms application is displayed on landscape mode. The orientation will be restored to portrait when the user leave that page.
I restore the orientation from within the ondisapearing method.
It work fine until I add the link from within that page to display other page. 
No matter which page is accessed, the orientation always restored to portrait, while what I want is when the user leave the page to the previous page, the orientation is restored to portrait, but the orientation is kept in landscape mode if the user is accessing other page.
The question: how can I detect if the user leave the page to go back to previous page or continue to other page?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: your code controls the navigation, so you should be able to tell if they are moving forward to a new page or backwards to an existing page

Comment: You can check the method to control the [Page.OnBackButtonPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onbackbuttonpressed?view=xamarin-forms).

Comment: You could get all the page in Navigation Stack using ```var stack = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack;```. and see if the page is in the stack.